# Datepicker problem when trying to make a second click in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker plugin on Jquery. Everything works fine at first glance. When I click the input field, it shows the calendar. Then I click on the input field again, it doesnt show up the calendar.

If I click outside of the input field that is related to datepicker and then try to click it again. This time calendar is shown. This is something related on focus but I couldnt solve it. How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

```
$(selector + '.datepickerFlexible').datepicker({

    defaultDate: '0',
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)),
    changeYear: true,
    selectDefaultDate: true,
    yearRange: '-0:+0',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="GeneralTextBox left lpush">
     <input name="TargetDate"  type="text" class="Input datepickerFlexible" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you user firebug? Any errors?

Comment: Yes No error is show up.Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you show us the HTML-code?

Comment: In runtime, what value will the variable "selector" have?

Comment: Thats the parent div that wraps the whole content. I have also same problem http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ in this example. This is maybe not a problem, but its not working how I want

Comment: add a spance in the '.datepickerFlexible' to ' .datepickerFlexible'

Comment: Unfortunately, its not about that. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have  tasted your code ..its works perfectly for me.
I think when you clicking second time there should be problem here **$(selector + '.datepickerFlexible')**

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you remove the word 'selector' from the first line.